# How to detect a memory leak system wide?

Tags: 10.04, memory, top, memory-leak

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to detect a memory leak?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152716/how-to-detect-a-memory-leak)

I'm using a Ubuntu Lucid box at work which just runs for ever (almost never shut it down). Since upgrading to Lucid I've noticed that after 2 or 3 weeks w/o rebooting, memory usage becomes huge: RAM completely full (3GB) and 6 GB swap.

I suspect this is caused by some app (or driver) leaking memory, but I have no clue which one it might be, because memory usage increases very slowly.

So, I need a program to detect if ANY process in my system is slowly leaking memory.

What I think would do it is a program which takes a daily measurement of the memory usage of each process (like top or htop), and shows me the evolution of that usage over the time.

Googled for it. Found nothing.

Comment: Please post what processes and modules you have active -- perhaps someone in your situation will find this question in the future and benefit from it.